# Nested Conditional Styling with CSS/JavaScript

Tags: css, reactjs, state

In my React app I have a box which is styled.
The component holds state. I would like to change the colour of the box dependant on the colour.

For example, if selectedID = 1, pink, if selectedID = 2, green etc and so on.

I've tried something like this with no success:

```
<InformationContainer
// style={ {backgroundColor: selectedID < 2  || selectedID > 2 ? '#ebedfb':'#ffe5e5'}}
style={ {backgroundColor: 
selectedID < 4 ? '#ffe5e5':
selectedID < 3  || selectedID > 2 ? '#414c97':
selectedID < 3  || selectedID > 3 ? '#65bb2c':
selectedID < 3  || selectedID > 3 ? 'yellow':
'white'
}}
>
```

I would like o have this for all 4 boxes and pieces of state.

Comment: What is the issue you are having, no background color at all or just sticks with some value and doesn't change? Can you also show how you set `selectedID`?

Comment: All that logic should be extracted to a function (or just a data object) on the parent component. Markup should be kept clean.

Comment: An ID is a string. How are you comparing to integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it seems like the selectedID will always be less than four so it never makes it past the first check. As well some of your checks don't make sense. Something like this would work better.

```
style={ {backgroundColor: 
    selectedID == 4 ? '#ffe5e5':
    selectedID == 3 ? '#414c97':
    selectedID == 2 ? '#65bb2c':
    selectedID == 1 ? 'yellow':
    'white'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a big fan nested ternaries (I'm not), you could extract that logic in a small function.

```
getBgColor(selectedID) {
  if(selectedID === 4) return '#ffe5e5';
  if(selectedID === 3) return '#414c97';
  if(selectedID === 2) return '#65bb2c';
  if(selectedID === 1) return '#yellow';
  return 'white';
}
// ***
<InformationContainer
  style={ {backgroundColor: getBgColor(selectedID)} }
>
```